# Why is the output of werkzeugs `generate_password_hash` not constant?

Tags: python, flask, password-encryption

When I run `werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash("Same password")` ([docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/utils/#werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash)) multiple times, the output is different each time.

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not constant?

Comment: Turns out i was truncating it when i was storing it in my database. As a result, i couldnt compare it properly :-)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question - I was rehashing in order to do the comparison instead of using the check_password_hash() method.  Wouldn't have known to do otherwise but for the answer to the question.  Upvote for both of you.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The password is *salted*, yes. The salt is added to the password before hashing, to ensure that the hash isn't useable in a [rainbow table attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-are-rainbow-tables-and-how-are-they-used).

Because the salt is randomly generated each time you call the function, the resulting password hash is also different. The returned hash includes the generated salt so that can still correctly verify the password.

Demo:

```
>>> from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
>>> generate_password_hash('foobar')
'pbkdf2:sha1:1000$tYqN0VeL$2ee2568465fa30c1e6680196f8bb9eb0d2ca072d'
>>> generate_password_hash('foobar')
'pbkdf2:sha1:1000$XHj5nlLU$bb9a81bc54e7d6e11d9ab212cd143e768ea6225d'
```

These two strings differ; but contain enough information to verify the password because the generated salt is included in each:

```
# pbkdf2:sha1:1000$tYqN0VeL$2ee2568465fa30c1e6680196f8bb9eb0d2ca072d
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   salt   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      algo info    ^^^^^^^^        actual hash of the password
  (PBKDF2 applied SHA1 1000 times)
```

Because the random salt is `tYqN0VeL` for one and `XHj5nlLU`, the resulting hash is also different.

The `foobar` password can still be verified against either hash:

```
>>> from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
>>> check_password_hash('pbkdf2:sha1:1000$tYqN0VeL$2ee2568465fa30c1e6680196f8bb9eb0d2ca072d', 'foobar')
True
>>> check_password_hash('pbkdf2:sha1:1000$XHj5nlLU$bb9a81bc54e7d6e11d9ab212cd143e768ea6225d', 'foobar')
True
```

Also see

- [Can you help me understand what a cryptographic “salt” is?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/can-you-help-me-understand-what-a-cryptographic-salt-is) (Cryptography.SE)
- [Why is using salt more secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/why-is-using-salt-more-secure) (Security.SE)

Comment: So if salt is visible in resulting hash — isn’t it less secure than to somehow store salts secretly?

Comment: @ЭлёржонКимсанов: Salts are there to defeat a rainbow table attack, which is a list of common passwords turned into hashes. Without a random salt, such a table is trivial to generate up front and then re-use over and over again. With a salt, you need to generate as many tables as there are possible salt values, and that is simply not feasible. The salt value itself **doesn't matter**, only that different passwords in the same database use different, random salt values. So no, the salt being visible is not a security risk, only not having proper random salt values is.