# How to verify password hash on Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, hash, flask-admin, flask-security

When we register a new user with [Flask-Admin](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin) it will automatically generate a password hash.

[image]

How to verify the hash..?
any similar method like `check_password_hash` on [bycript](https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or like `check_password_hash` from **werkzeug.security**..?

I try this [verify_password](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html#flask_security.utils.verify_password) from **Flask-Security** but seems not work.

This is the snippet of my code:

**config.py**

```
SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH = "pbkdf2_sha256"
SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT = "ATGUOHAELKiubahiughaerGOJAEGj"
```

and this is my **models.py**

```
from flask_security import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def check_password(self, password):
        # return verify_password(self.password, password)   # from Flask-Security
        # return verify_and_update_password(self.password, password) # from Flask-Security
        return check_password(self.password, password) # from werkzeug.security
```

No one of the `chek_password` work when I try to verify the password hash that automatically generated from Flask-Admin when a user first register, it always returns False like this.

```
>>> u1=db.session.query(User).filter_by(email='zidanecr7kaka@gmail.com').first()
>>> u1.check_password('123456')
False
```

But when I try to set the password manually like the bellow ways:

```
def set_password(self, password):
    # self.password = encrypt_password(password)    # from Flask-Security
    # self.password = hash_password(password)         # from Flask-Security
    self.password = generate_password_hash(password) # from werkzeug.security
```

It return True:

```
>>> u1=db.session.query(User).filter_by(email='zidanecr7kaka@gmail.com').first()
>>> u1.set_password('123456')
>>> u1.check_password('123456')
True
```

But when I try to `check_password` from password hash that automatically generated from **Flask Admin** when a user first register, it always returns False value:

So the point of my questions is, how to verify the password hash using Flask-Admin..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23461447/8070090) of my case.

so I making news module called **utils.py**, and here is the code:

```
from flask_security.utils import _security, get_hmac, _pwd_context


def verify_password(password, password_hash):
    """Returns ``True`` if the password matches the supplied hash.

    :param password: A plaintext password to verify
    :param password_hash: The expected hash value of the password (usually form your database)
    """
    if _security.password_hash != 'plaintext':
        password = get_hmac(password)

    return _pwd_context.verify(password, password_hash)
```

and then I modify my **models.py** be like this:

```
from flask_security import UserMixin
from app.utils import verify_password


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String())

    def check_password(self, password):
        return verify_password(password, self.password)
```

Very thanks to who has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23461447/8070090) that.

Answer (score 3):

flask-admin examples include [this](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/7fa26ab227868ff7512bb25c26a30fd7d69184bc/examples/auth-flask-login/app.py#L68) commented code:

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

...

    # we're comparing the plaintext pw with the the hash from the db
    if not check_password_hash(user.password, self.password.data):
    # to compare plain text passwords use
    # if user.password != self.password.data:
        raise validators.ValidationError('Invalid password')
```