# SQLAlchemy Relationships Many to Many X 2

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect a transaction table to a member table where there are many transactions per member but there are two members per transactions (a buyer and a seller).  How do I create a relationship that will allow me to grab a memberID for the seller and a memberID for a buyer for each transaction?

class Member(db.Model, UserMixin):

```
__tablename__ = 'members'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
# exchangeID = db.Column(db.Integer(6),db.ForeignKey('exchanges.exchangeID'),nullable=False)
company_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
category = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, default='Other')
description = db.Column(db.Text)
profile_image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default_profile.png')
email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
# username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
# password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
address = db.Column(db.String(128))
phone = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
fein = db.Column(db.Integer)
webaddress = db.Column(db.String(64))
twitter = db.Column(db.String(24))
exchange_approved = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
users = db.relationship('User', backref='company',lazy=True)
transactions = db.relationship('Transaction', backref='company',lazy=True)
listings = db.relationship('Listing', backref='company',lazy=True)
credit = db.relationship('Credit', backref='company',lazy=True)


def __init__(self,exchange_name,company_name,category,mail,address,phone,fein):
    # self.exchange_name = exchange_name
    self.company_name = company_name
    self.category = category
    self.email = email
    self.address = address
    self.phone = phone
    self.fein = fein

def __repr__(self):
    return f"Company Name: {self.company_name}"
```

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

```
__tablename__ = 'users'

members = db.relationship(Member)

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
companyID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('members.id'),nullable=False)
buy_transactions = db.relationship('Transaction', backref='buyer',lazy=True)
sell_transactions = db.relationship('Transaction', backref='seller',lazy=True)
# exchangeID = db.Column(db.Integer(6), db.ForeignKey('exchanges.exchangeID'),nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
phone_number = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
user_type = db.Column(db.String(14))
member_approved = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
limited_trade = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
member_imposed_limit = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)

def __init__(self,username,password,company_name,email,phone):
    self.username = username
    self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
    self.companyID = companyID
    self.email = email
    self.phone = phone

def check_password(self,password):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432478/flask-generate-password-hash-not-constant-output
    return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"UserName: {self.username}"
```

class Transaction(db.Model, UserMixin):

```
__tablename__ = 'transactions'

members = db.relationship(Member)

transactionID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
companyID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('members.id'),nullable=False)
sellerID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False)
buyerID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False)
seller = relationship("User", foreign_keys='Transaction.sellerID')
buyer = relationship("User", foreign_keys='Transaction.buyerID')
amount = db.Column(db.Numeric(5,2), nullable=False)
commission = db.Column(db.Numeric(5,2), nullable=False)
transactionDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
approved = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
commission_paid = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
posted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

def __init__(self,sellerID,buyerID,amount):
    self.sellerID = sellerID
    self.buyerID = buyerID
    self.amount = amount

def __repr__(self):
    return f"Trasaction Id: {self.transactionID} --- Date: {self.date} --- Amount: {self.amount}"
```

I am getting a 'relationship' not defined but that is obvious as I don't understand how to connect the tables as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is an association table, that should link the two tables which need to have many-many relationship. Below is a very simple example of a many-many relationship which should give you an idea on how to proceed from there.

This is how your `models.py` should look like

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + 'testdb.sql'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# Please note the below association table needs to be actual database table and not a model class.
stu_subs = db.Table('stu_subs', db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id')),
                    db.Column('subject_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subjects.id')))


class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    # Note the secondary attribute below, that actually sets up a many-to-many relationship
    subj = db.relationship('Subjects', secondary=stu_subs, backref=db.backref('student', lazy='dynamic'))


class Subjects(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

Finally this is how you are going to access the table fields from each table.

```
>>> db.create_all()
>>> from dummy import Student, Subjects
>>> student1 = Student(name="Student1")
>>> student2 = Student(name="Student2")
>>> subj1 = Subjects(name='subject1')
>>> subj2 = Subjects(name='subject2')
>>> subj3 = Subjects(name='subject3')
>>> subj4 = Subjects(name='subject4')
>>> db.session.add_all([student1, student2, subj1, subj2,subj3,subj4])
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> stu1 = Student.query.filter_by(id=1)
>>> stu2 = Student.query.filter_by(id=2).first()
>>> sub1 = Student.query.filter_by(name='subject1').first()
>>> sub2 = Subjects.query.filter_by(name='subject2').first()
>>> sub3 = Subjects.query.filter_by(name='subject3').first()
>>> sub4 = Subjects.query.filter_by(name='subject4').first()
>>> stu1.subj.extend([sub1,sub2,sub4])
>>> stu2.subj.extend([sub2,sub4])
>>> stu1.subj
[<Subjects 1>, <Subjects 2>, <Subjects 4>]
>>> subj2.student.all()
[<Student 2>, <Student 1>]
>>> >>> stu1.subj[0].name
'subject1'
>>> for subj in  stu1.subj:
...     print(subj.name)
... 
subject1
subject2
subject4
>>> for stu in subj2.student:
...     print(stu.name)
... 
Student2
Student1
>>>
```

This is just a very basic example, ofcourse you need to extend it in your case. You would have to create multiple association tables for each `db.realtionship` attribute and so on.

Comment: if in this example, one student were to be a TA and you needed to add a connection between subject and class where classes had students but also a TA also drawn from the student table.                                                                                                                                    
stu_subs = db.Table('stu_subs', db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id')),
                 db.Column('subject_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subjects.id')), 
                 db.Column('teachersAssistant_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subjects.id')))

Comment: in my case I have buyers and sellers that are both members.  So ultimately I want to see transaction.buyer and transaction.seller where both came from the member table.

Comment: You are missing a point here that the association table has to be between the two tables that actually need to have relationship with each other and the association table has primary keys of two tables as its foreign keys. So if i were to have a seperate TA table which need to have a relationship with Student table then i would need another association table for TA and Student. I will write the code for your example and update my answer but for now i think they way you have defined relationships in users table is not correct. Check out the flask sqlalchemy documentation for examples.

Comment: Thanks Rohit.  For this example there is no separate TA table. Just a field for students and a field for a TA which comes from a connection to the student table.  What I am really trying to do is grab a buyer and seller from my members table every time a transaction is booked.  Therefore I need to lookup the buyer and the seller in the member table.

Comment: Thanks Rohit.  For this example there is no separate TA table. Just a field for students and a field for a TA which comes from a connection to the student table.  What I am really trying to do is grab a buyer and seller from my members table every time a transaction is booked.  Therefore I need to lookup the buyer and the seller in the member table.

Comment: Yes thats correcte, you can access all the columns of the other table with which you have relationship. So in your case if user table has relationship with member and let's say member table has fields like buyer and seller you should be able to access this from user table like User1.member.buyer etc..

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is helpful for you and have you direction to fix ur code.

Answer (score -1):

ok...this was pretty dumb. I stopped getting the error once I put db in front of relationship so db.relationship.  I haven't built out the transaction form yet to test the relationship back and forth but the site at least comes up and runs.  Thx.